# The joint probability exponential and gamma distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Assume that $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ are independent and identically distributed exponential with parameter $\lambda>0$.
Furthermore, let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ follows as  $Gamma(n,\lambda)$ distribution, for which the PDF is given:

$$
f(x \mid \lambda)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x}, & \text { if } x>0 \\
0, & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.
$$

Compute the joint probability between $X_1$ and $Y$.

Question:

We have independent between $X_1$ and $Y$?

Comment: pdf of $X_i$ missing.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I just added

Comment: Since $Y=X_1+$ stuff independent of $X_1$, the answer will be no: $X_1$ and $Y$ will not be independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_1$ and $Y$ are not independent. Since $Y - X_1 = \sum_{i = 2}^n X_i$ and $X_i, X_j$ independent for $i \ne j$ we have that $X_1$ and $Y - X_1$ are independent. This would mean
$$
\text{Cov} \left( X_1, Y - X_1 \right) = 0
$$
But then,
$$ 
\text{Cov} \left( X_1, Y \right) = \text{Cov} \left( X_1, Y - X_1 \right) + \text{Cov} \left( X_1, X_1 \right) = \text{Var}\left[ X_1  \right] \ne 0
$$
So $X_1$ and $Y$ are not independent.

To compute the probability distribution of $(X_1, Y)$ you will want to condition on $X_1$. It is intuitive that for fixed $x$, $f_{Y \mid X_1} (y \mid x)$ will be the probability density function of a Gamma distribution with parameters $n - 1, \lambda$, translated $x$ units in the $x$-direction. This is because

$$\mathbf{P} \left( Y \le y \mid X_1 = x \right) = \mathbf{P} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \le y \, \big\rvert \, X_1 = x \right) = \mathbf{P} \left( \sum_{i = 2}^n X_i \le y - x \right)$$

and $\sum_{i = 2}^n X_i$ follows a gamma distribution with parameters $n - 1, \lambda$. Hence,

$$f_{Y \mid X_1} \left( y \mid x \right) = \frac{\lambda^{n - 1} (y - x)^{n - 1} e^{-\lambda(y - x)}}{\Gamma(n)}$$

Then the joint probability density function is

$$f_{Y, X_1} (x, y) = f_{Y \mid X_1} (y \mid x) f_X(x) = \frac{\lambda^n (y - x)^{n - 1} e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(n)}$$

for all $y \ge x \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks, so it’s easy way to compute joint probability?

Comment: I've edited the answer with an explanation of how to compute the density

Comment: Are you sure about equation $f_{Y \mid X_1}$?

Comment: It's correct:  $f_{Y \mid X_1} \left( y \mid x \right) = \frac{\lambda^{n - 1} (y - x)^{n - 2} e^{-\lambda(y - x)}}{\Gamma(n-1)}$

Comment: And Y is not discrete! Should be: $P(Y \leq y|X_1 = x) = P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \leq y |X_1 = x) = P(\sum_{i=2}^n X_i \leq y-x)$